# How to lock array for aggregation in Parallel.For

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking

I am trying to iterate through a 2D array  and then add to parts of another 2D array in a Parallel.For
loop.
I have found examples where an accumulation is being done inside the loop
on a single variable but am not sure what to do here.
GridB is doing accumulation so surely it needs to be locked as items in it could
be added to from different threads
If it needs to be locked how do you go about locking an entire array like this?

```
int[,] GridA = new int[D + 2, D + 2];
int[,] GridB = new int[D + 2, D + 2];

Parallel.For(1, D+1 , r =>
{
for (int c = 1; c <= D ; c++)
    if (GridA[r, c] != 0)
    {
        int v = GridA[r, c];

        GridB[r - 1, c - 1] += v;
        GridB[r - 1, c] += v;
        GridB[r - 1, c + 1] += v;

        GridB[r, c - 1] += v;
        GridB[r, c + 1] += v;

        GridB[r + 1, c - 1] += v;
        GridB[r + 1, c] += v;
        GridB[r + 1, c + 1] += v;
    }
});
```

Comment: It'd be easier if you used jagged array `[][]` instead of a two dimensional array `[,]`.

Comment: What is the advantage of a jagged array in this case?

Comment: As long as the threads don't access the same elements in the array, you can do this without locking.

Comment: @user2425056 You could lock the three relevant rows in `GridB`, which would pretty much secure the threading, while still allowing them to switch properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just lock `GridB` like so:

```
Parallel.For(1, D+1 , r =>
{
  for (int c = 1; c <= D ; c++)
  {
    if (GridA[r, c] != 0)
    {
      int v = GridA[r, c];
      lock(GridB) 
      { 
        GridB[r - 1, c - 1] += v;
        // etc.
      }
    }
  }
});
```

However, you are serializing all access to `GridB` which sort of defeats the purpose of using multiple threads.

If all you want to do is add a fixed value to each element, `Interlocked.Add` in the `System.Threading` namespace will do the add atomically, so you don't need to take out a lock on the whole array.

Here's a sample of the usage:

```
Parallel.For(1, D+1 , r =>
{
    for (int c = 1; c <= D ; c++)
      if (GridA[r, c] != 0)
      {
         int v = GridA[r, c];

          Interlocked.Add(ref GridB[r - 1, c - 1], v);
          // rinse, repeat
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is working. At least the algorithm is running about 2x faster. Will still have to check for accuracy against the serial version.

Comment: @Yorye, I have changed the algorithm to use jagged arrays and the speedup is noticeable. While this was not the answer to my question it lead me to a fruitful discovery. Thanks.